# Why are usage reports of gcp not delivered to the storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, report, google-compute-engine, bucket

I tried enabling the usage export feature for cloud storage, also the storage writer permission got attached to the bucket still, I am not receiving any reports

Comment: Can you be more specific about your situation.